# Best practice to devide layout to tiles in android?

Tags: android, layout

I'm trying to recreate the layotu from google trips,

[image]

and i cannot align the side tiles one after another and still KEEP the screen divided by half.

this is the layout that ive got so far

[image]

my layout xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/content_slides__screen"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="msn.apps.textswipehd.Slides_Screen.Slides_Screen"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_slides__screen">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/upperLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/mainImage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/slides_bg" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mainHeadlineText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:shadowColor="@color/text_shadow"
            android:shadowDx="1"
            android:shadowDy="1"
            android:shadowRadius="2"
            android:text="projectName"
            android:textColor="@color/projectWhite"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/editButton"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_create_white_24dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/upperLayout">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/linearUpper"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="180dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark">

            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/upperRightLayout"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

            </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>



        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearUpper"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="180dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark">

            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/upperRightLayout2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

            </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

how can i align the side tiles like the trips app ? 
do you  have a better practice to do the tiles layouts ?

Comment: use recycler view with staggeredlayout manager

Comment: Chief Madog, are your content static or changing from server. Both will use RecyclerView at the end, but with little changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of layouts are achieved by the concept of **staggered gridview**

Here is the links for the tutorial of staggered gridview

https://inducesmile.com/android/android-staggeredgridlayoutmanager-example-tutorial/

https://github.com/etsy/AndroidStaggeredGrid

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by going to the *dimens.xml* which is in *values.xml*. There you can specify the horizontal and vertical margin from layout according to your need. Also go through **GridView**. Hope it helps !